# In Linux 2.4, is the youngest child list cylic?

Tags: c, linux, list, linux-kernel, kernel

regarding the task_struct lists:

```
/* 
 * pointers to (original) parent process, youngest child, younger sibling,
 * older sibling, respectively.  (p->father can be replaced with 
 * p->p_pptr->pid)
 */
task_t *p_opptr, *p_pptr, *p_cptr, *p_ysptr, *p_osptr;
```

I'm using these pointers to run through process's children.
What I don't understand (and had hard time understanding from kernel code) is if the youngest child list ends in null or is it cyclic?

Can I run through all `p_cptr` untill I reach `NULL`, or should I expect returning to the head again?

Comment: Linked list in kernel is [circular doubly-linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list#Circular_doubly-linked_lists). So the last element (tail) is pointing to the first element (head). Take a look at [for_each_process()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L2529) macro.

Comment: It doesn't matter what is the list that you are using. All lists are circular in kernel. It's achieved by list functions implementation: they all are trying to make list circular after each operation. All you need to use for your task is `list_for_each()` and `list_entry()` functions. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207160/kernel-how-to-iterate-the-children-of-the-current-process) for details.

Comment: I am not iterating list through `list_head` pointers, but by `task_t` pointers directly.
There is no `prev`, `next` I'm going through, so it's not exactly the same case.
I'm accessing `p_cptr` and `p_osptr` for each process, I just don't understand what to expect for a process that doesn't have a child/older sibling.

Comment: What is actually `task_t`? And am I correct that you are talking about user-space? Because I couldn't find any `task_t` types in kernel. So it's very confusing for me: you are having `task_struct` (which is kernel structure) mentioned in the title, and then you are talking about some `task_t` type.

Comment: Kernel-space.
task_t is just a typedef for task_struct

from sched.h:
`typedef struct task_struct task_t;`

Comment: What is the kernel version you are using?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below. I haven't tested it on kernel 2.4 (only on 4.0), but I think it should work for 2.4 with little modifications. I used `kthreadd` process as a parent, for example, because it has a lot of children.

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/list.h>

#define KTHREADD_PID 2

static int __init ktdf_init(void)
{
    struct task_struct *kthreadd_task;
    struct list_head *list;

    /* Find kthreadd task by PID */
    kthreadd_task = pid_task(find_vpid(KTHREADD_PID), PIDTYPE_PID);
    pr_debug("Process name: %s\n", kthreadd_task->comm);

    /* Iterate over all children of kthreadd_task */
    list_for_each(list, &kthreadd_task->children) {
        struct task_struct *task;

        /* Get next child */
        task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);
        pr_debug("  Child name: %s\n", task->comm);
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit ktdf_exit(void)
{
}

module_init(ktdf_init);
module_exit(ktdf_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Sam Protsenko");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("kthreadd children finder module");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

So as you can see, `.sibling` list is [circular doubly-linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list#Circular_doubly-linked_lists), which means the last element of this list (tail) points to the first element (head). You can see it from [list_for_each()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/list.h#L408) macro implementation.

The output in `dmesg` (after module is loaded by `insmod`):

```
Process name: kthreadd
  Child name: ksoftirqd/0
  Child name: ksoftirqd/1
  Child name: ksoftirqd/2
  Child name: ksoftirqd/3
  Child name: kworker/0:0
  Child name: kworker/0:0H
  Child name: kworker/0:1
  Child name: kworker/0:1H
  Child name: kworker/0:2
  ...
```

You can check it by `ps` command:

```
$ ps auxf
```

Which gave me the same process tree:

```
[kthreadd]
\_ [ksoftirqd/0]
\_ [ksoftirqd/1]
\_ [ksoftirqd/2]
\_ [ksoftirqd/3]
\_ [kworker/0:0]
\_ [kworker/0:0H]
\_ [kworker/0:1]
\_ [kworker/0:1H]
\_ [kworker/0:2]
...
```

Comment: This solution is working, but not on 2.4 since I do not have the `children` list as in newer kernels.
I only have the pointers mentioned at the question.

Comment: I finally found out what you were talking about: [link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h?v=2.4.37#L346). Unfortunately, I don't have kernel 2.4 on my machine so even if I come up with some code -- I wouldn't be able to test it.

Comment: I encourage you to `grep` over your kernel and look for some actual usage of those pointers you mentioned (and maybe for `sibling` word). You may also want to use LXR for this purpose.

Comment: Didn't manage to find exactly what I needed so I added an extra-safety check to make sure I'm not going through something I already visited.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

at least in `2.4.18`, both of the lists that you are interested in aren't cyclic (i.e. the list which is made of `p_cptr` fields, and the list made of `p_ysptr` and `p_osptr` fields).

i deduced that from some code i found in [kernel/fork.c](http://sop.upv.es/lxr/http/source/kernel/fork.c?v=2.4.18) in `do_fork` (the main fork routine):

```
p = alloc_task_struct();
...
*p = *current;
...
p->p_cptr = NULL;
...
SET_LINKS(p);
```

while giving birth to the newborn process, we allocate a `task_struct` for it, and copy the `task_struct` of the parent process into it.
the third line terminates the `p_cptr` list with `NULL`.

`SET_LINKS` is defined in [include/linux/sched.h](http://sop.upv.es/lxr/http/source/include/linux/sched.h?v=2.4.18):

```
#define SET_LINKS(p) do { \
    ...
    (p)->p_ysptr = NULL; \
    if (((p)->p_osptr = (p)->p_pptr->p_cptr) != NULL) \
        (p)->p_osptr->p_ysptr = p; \
    (p)->p_pptr->p_cptr = p; \
    ...
} while (0)
```

the newborn is always the youngest child, so when `SET_LINKS` sets its `p_ysptr` to `NULL`, it terminates the youngest child end (of the siblings list) with `NULL`.

if the newborn isn't the first (i.e. oldest) child, then `SET_LINKS` doesn't change the `p_osptr` of the oldest child.
but if the newborn is the first child, `(p)->p_pptr->p_cptr` is still `NULL` when
`(p)->p_osptr = (p)->p_pptr->p_cptr` is executed, and so `p_osptr` of the first child (which is the oldest child) is set to `NULL`.
thus, `SET_LINKS` also terminates the oldest child end of the list with `NULL`.