# Why number of sibling processes is 1 when it has no sibling process?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls

If I use the following statement to iterate the sibling processes of a process without a sibling process, I get 1 rather than 0, and that sibling process seems to have the pid 0.

```
list_for_each(list, &curr->sibling){
   struct task_struct* task = list_entry(list,struct task_struct, sibling);
   printk("%d\n",(int)task->pid);
}
```

What happened here?

Comment: Correct iteration over process's siblings uses `curr->children` list, not a `curr->sibling`. See, e.g., [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207160/kernel-how-to-iterate-the-children-of-the-current-process/).

Comment: That question is to list children of a process, but this is to list its siblings..

Comment: There is **no list of siblings**. Field `.sibling` is a *linkage* within list of **children**. If you want only siblings, you may iterate over list of parent's children and exclude the task itself.

Comment: But I do not know why I can use the above code to get the right number of siblings...but the number is just 1+number of siblings..

Comment: If I use curr->parent->children to get the siblings, the case when curr==curr->parent does not work, should I just say number 0 process has 0 siblings in this case?

Comment: `...but the number is just 1+number of siblings` - this is because you actually look into the list with head `curr->parent->children`, and this head "is element of" the list. With common list iteration (using its actual head), its head is automatically excluded from the iterated elements. But when iterating using list's element as head, you need to exclude actual lists's head manually. `the case when curr==curr->parent does not work` - Root process has no siblings.